# Scala - Try transform vs match vs map method

Tags: scala, performance, coding-style, try-catch, code-cleanup

I have read about **transform** method on Try and compare this method with other methods to figure out which one will be more clear for coding. I show you the code below

```
val value: Try[Int] = Try("1".toInt)
.transform(f => Success(f), e => Success(0))


val value2: Try[Int] = Try("1".toInt) match {
    case Success(f) => Success(f)
    case Failure(e) => Success(0)
}


val value3: Try[Int] = Try("1".toInt)
    .map(f => f)
    .recover {
      case e: Exception => 0
    }
```

I would like to know which one will be better in these cases and the reason why is it?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to recover from any (non-fatal) exception, it makes more sense for the result to be `Int` than `Try[Int]`, since you know you have a success value, so the most idiomatic solution would look like this:

```
scala> import scala.util.Try
import scala.util.Try

scala> val value4: Int = Try("1".toInt).getOrElse(0)
value4: Int = 1
```

If your actual logic is more complex, or you just prefer being really explicit, you could pattern match:

```
scala> import scala.util.{ Failure, Success, Try }
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

scala> val value5: Int = Try("1".toInt) match {
     |   case Success(i) => i
     |   case Failure(_) => 0
     | }
value5: Int = 1
```

If for some reason you really want to end up with a `Try[Int]` even though you know it will always be a `Success`, I'd suggest using `recover` and `NonFatal`:

```
scala> import scala.util.Try, scala.util.control.NonFatal
import scala.util.Try
import scala.util.control.NonFatal

scala> val value5: Try[Int] = Try("1".toInt).recover {
     |   case NonFatal(_) => 0
     | }
value5: scala.util.Try[Int] = Success(1)
```

Note that this leaves out the unnecessary `.map(f => f)` from your `value3`, and also replaces the catch-all `case e: Exception` with Scala's `NonFatal` extractor, which won't match fatal exceptions like `OutOfMemoryError` (you generally can't recover from these exceptions, so you don't want to catch them here).

Even in this case, though, it wouldn't be idiomatic to use `transform`, since you can express the operation with a less powerful combinator (`recover`), and you should always prefer the simplest solution that does what you need.

There's not really any reason to return a `Try[Int]` here, though, so I'd just go with `getOrElse`.